# How to grab all descendant elements but only until certain element with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have follow xml

```
<element id="1">
    <choice>
        <sequence>
            <element id="11">
                <group>
                    <element id="111">
                        <!-- ... -->
                    </element>
                </group>
            </element>
            <element id="12">
                <element id="121">
                    <!-- ... -->
                </element>
            </element>
        </sequence>
    </choice>
</element>
```

between current `<element>` and children `<element>` nodes may be any combination of `<choice>`, `<sequence>` and `<group>` nodes. Or they may not be. How to grab all immediately descendants `<element>` nodes in current `<element>` but without `<element>` nodes which are their descendants.

In context one of `<element>` node, I want to write something like:
`./(choice|sequence|group)*/element`

but it not works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve it only by using again the xpath which selects "root" element. For example, if you select it by xpath `//element[@id="1"]` then

```
.//element[ancestor::element[1] = //element[@id="1"]]
```

selects what you want. It will find `element` which has not other `element` between it and 'root'

You can test it there - https://eval.in/781145 set id = 1, id = 12 ....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I correctly understood the issue... Try below `XPath` expression and let me know if it's not what you want:

```
./*[self::choice or self::sequence or self::group]/element
```

Comment: It seems it works. But my example was too simple. I checked on real data and it does not work. Now I will give an example with my real data.

Comment: With the help of your expression, I understood, but what needs to be done so that not only the `<element>` nodes but also the `<attribute>`. `.../element|attribute` not works

Comment: `.../*[self::element or self::attribute] ` not works too

Comment: Do you mean this `//element/*[self::choice or self::sequence or self::group]/(element | attribute)`?

Comment: Yes. But in this case, both <element> and <attribute> can be on the immediate child of the current <element>. Instead of `<choice>` or nearby with him.

Comment: Hmm... No, I don't think so. In this case `element` or `attribute` could be a *child  of the direct child of `choice`/`sequence`/`group`*, but not the *direct child of `element`*.. Could you share more detailed `HTML` sample and desired output?

Comment: First, i see you from Ukraine, may be you speak Russian? Second, I would be glad, but it xsd file contains great than 10k lines.